# How to redirect to a specific scene on start-up, but allow redirection afterwards in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, scene

I have a game with multiple scenes. I'd like it to always redirect the user to the scene "Opening Scene" on startup, no matter what scene is currently open.

I could use an always sensor hooked up to a scene actuator, but this means that I can't switch back to any of the scenes after startup, because they will automatically redirect back to "Opening Scene".

Is there any way to do this so that the scene gets redirected at startup, but after that allows redirecting to other scenes?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! We're glad to have you! You've received a couple of down votes because your question is poorly asked. Some newcomers get frustrated because they expect this site to work like a forum... but it doesn't. Please take a minute to review the [tour] and get a feel for how we do things in the StackExchange network (and Blender.SE specifically). Clear, concise, professionally asked questions tend to get better answers. When you put in the effort to use proper sentences, punctuation and capitalization, we feel better about putting in the effort to answer your question ;-)

Comment: @Matt erm... u know i've been on blender.se for a while right... and i also don't give a crap about down votes. also how am i using this for a forum. i asked a question and i want an answer. i'm using this site for a q&a which is exactly what this site is meant for. Plus, how is it poorly asked. so long as the people know what i'm asking. if u think its poorly asked u edit it.(sides i'm only 13 years  and in my eyes i asked it as good as it could be asked).

Comment: If you've been on B.SE for a while, then act like it. I'm offering some advice because what you're doing is "sub-optimal." If you want to do your own thing, lemme know how all that works out for you...

Comment: @Matt u aren't offering me jack! i asked u how am i using this as a forum. no answer. i asked u how my question is unprofessional. no answer.

Comment: Strangely, that response doesn't make me more eager to help, either...

Comment: @Matt And Skrub. u were the one who started talking to me about all this crap. and yet u don't answer me when i ask about what u said. if u ain't gonna be helpful then screw off.

Comment: I think that what @Matt was trying to say, was that when you use terms such as,"This is difficult because I can like on every scene," it makes your question look "unprofessional". Also, you have only two sentences in your question. "(three if you count, "how can I fix this") One of your sentences is a run-on. Essentially, your question just *looks* poorly written. However, that is how it is now. The edit history shows that when you posted the question, it looked like it was sent to the Stack Exchange network as a text-message.

Comment: Also, the title you used was, "**Complicated scene stuff**" When most users see a vague title like that, they read it as, "*I'm a noob, I can't figure this out, and I'm not going to put much effort into figuring out what I'm trying to do, or explain it in a question so I'll just say - HHEEELLLPP!!!!*"

Comment: to put it another way, I think the point that @Matt was trying to get across is that u got teh ouchy votes cuz like your post stunk and like we at dis site want it so whenever we get a qweston that is that so stinkin' aweful it automatically goes to the delete place but dis is difficult cuz the system ain't that good yet, so we gotta do the down voteing instead.

Comment: I'd downvote your post too, but I know how annoying it is to join a new site, ask your first question, and have it downvoted just because you didn't know what was expected.

Comment: @X-27 Just to clarify, my first comment was on the original post, before it was edited by a helpful member. Punctuation, proper capitalization, all these things (listed in my original comment) tell the rest of the community that the OP is taking the community seriously. I've got all the patience in the world for someone who is trying. I've got no time for someone who just wants to throw shade. The OP is invited to evaluate whether or not their 13yo 'tude got them what they wanted.

Comment: interesting - after the most recent edit, the question actually is rather good. in fact, it has received three upvotes in addition to the three downvotes it had before. My Upvote is about to make the total four, because I have run into this same problem before. This should just go to show that low- effort questions do not help you get answers.

Comment: @X-27 k. although i am not new here idk that people cared so much about this professional crap. i'll try to fix this in the future

Comment: @X-27 also if u have run in to the same problem before do u happen to know an answer

Comment: @Matt Also sorry for getting so ticked at u. i wuz just in a rush and didn't understand what u  where trying to say to me.

Comment: the problems I've run into have been slightly different - I wanted to have a menu scene, and multiple level scenes. in order to have the game be able to pause, I needed a background scene running to wait and pause the game, and then resume it. Where do I add the logic to create that background scene? In the menu? No... when a level is won, and the player returns to the menu, it would add the wait-for-pause scene again, which is a no-no. Essentially, I Had an initialization scene. the player started there, that scene added the background wait-for-pause scene, and added the menu.

Comment: But that doesn't really help you here. The easiest thing I can think of it add a large text object in front of the camera. (set to no-colision and invisible) that says, "YOU MUST START THE GAME IN THE MENU"

Comment: @gamer103 No worries. I appreciate your effort. There's always time to be dignified and courteous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In general I suggest to start the game with the current scene. A dependency to a specific scene will make development much harder as you always need to go through this opening scene. Switching right at the beginning increases load time.*

## Logic handler

For easier handling I suggest to create a group with one object that performs the switch. This way you can easily create one instance at each single scene without creating it again and again.

Another option is to link an object between the scenes.

## Concept

At game start you want to switch to the opening scene when:
- the opening scene was not visited before

You need a sort of store/restore method.

## Storage

As you switch scenes, I suggest to store such information in a Python module. It will survive any scene switch (in difference to object properties). The storage will survive as long as the game session runs.

## Code

The code is pretty simple. Please keep in mind it should run in module mode (script mode will not work this way).

*caller.py*

```
alreadyCalled = False

def isFirstCall(controller):
    global alreadyCalled

    if alreadyCalled:
        return 

    alreadyCalled = True

    for actuator in controller.actuators:
        controller.activate(actuator)
```

## Setup

```
Always Sensor -> Python Controller Module: caller.isFirstCall -> Scene Actuator: to opening scene
```

## Remarks

This will work with the first call "caller.py". Any subsequent execution of "isFirstCall" will not activate the actuators even when executed within the same frame.